# How did the Harvesters know to attack Cheyenne Mountain?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

In the first film it's assumed that the Harvesters knew where to attack, because they were the ones who abducted Russel (the alien encounter he had that people said he was crazy about) and in the case of Area 51, it was where the counter attack was sent from.

In *Resurgence*, during the attack, the Harvesters send out an attack ship which destroys Cheyenne Mountain where the entire Presidential Chain-of-Command was, instead of Area 51 where the Fleet was sent from.

But given how much the world has changed since the first attack, most information from Russel would be inaccurate at best and that's assuming the 2nd Harvester Mother Ship had gotten the same info (the intro to the movie suggests there is a communications delay from Earth to where the 2nd Harvester Mother Ship was).

So how did the Harvesters know to attack Cheyenne Mountain rather than Area 51 which launched the attack?

Comment: I'm guessing they'd read the script in advance

Comment: As you say, you are assuming they are the ones that abducted Russel; which we honestly don't know. But even if they did I am sure the collective gathering from all the abductees would have given them their basic plan of attack, not just Russel... why would they only go off the information gathered from just one individual? I believe there are also scenes in both films were we see sophisticated scanning/visual equipment that would likely have given them a leg up on where key stuff was as well... which is how I assumed they knew what to do.